# Como modificar os valores de um table td se ele tiver um caractere especifico?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma tabela que apresenta dados dinâmicos, alguns deles são e-mails, como faço para modificar o valor deles, adicionando a tag `<kbd>` e `</kbd>` entre o valor de cada um usando apenas javascript?

**Exemplo:** `test@domain.com`
**Esperado:** `<kbd>test@domain.com</kbd>`

Dessa forma, qualquer valor que contenha um `@` entra na regra de modificação, até `semdomain@config...`.

Código da tabela dinâmica:

```html
<div class="tablebg">
    <table id="sortabletbl0" class="datatable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th width="20">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall0">
                </th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=id">ID</a> </th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=product">Produto/Serviço</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=domain">Domínio</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=clientname">Nome do Cliente</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=amount">Preço</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=billingcycle">Ciclo de Pagamento</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=nextduedate">Próximo Vencimento</a></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedclients[]" value="5" class="checkall">
                </td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=5">5</a></td>
                <td>Conta Serviço A <span class="label pending">Pending</span></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=5">(Nenhum Domínio)</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientssummary.php?userid=1">Teste Teste</a></td>
                <td>R$0.00 BRL</td>
                <td>Gratuito</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedclients[]" value="4" class="checkall">
                </td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=4">4</a></td>
                <td>Conta Serviço A <span class="label active">Active</span></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=4">test@domain.com</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientssummary.php?userid=1">Teste Teste</a></td>
                <td>R$0.00 BRL</td>
                <td>Gratuito</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedclients[]" value="3" class="checkall">
                </td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=3">3</a></td>
                <td>Conta Serviço A <span class="label active">Active</span></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=3">semdomain@config...</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientssummary.php?userid=1">Teste Teste</a></td>
                <td>R$0.00 BRL</td>
                <td>Gratuito</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso, de forma que o resultado fosse o mesmo como demonstrado abaixo?

```html
<div class="tablebg">
    <table id="sortabletbl0" class="datatable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th width="20">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall0">
                </th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=id">ID</a> </th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=product">Produto/Serviço</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=domain">Domínio</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=clientname">Nome do Cliente</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=amount">Preço</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=billingcycle">Ciclo de Pagamento</a></th>
                <th><a href="/admin/services?orderby=nextduedate">Próximo Vencimento</a></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedclients[]" value="5" class="checkall">
                </td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=5">5</a></td>
                <td>Conta Serviço A <span class="label pending">Pending</span></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=5">(Nenhum Domínio)</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientssummary.php?userid=1">Teste Teste</a></td>
                <td>R$0.00 BRL</td>
                <td>Gratuito</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedclients[]" value="4" class="checkall">
                </td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=4">4</a></td>
                <td>Conta Serviço A <span class="label active">Active</span></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=4"><kbd>test@domain.com</kbd></a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientssummary.php?userid=1">Teste Teste</a></td>
                <td>R$0.00 BRL</td>
                <td>Gratuito</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedclients[]" value="3" class="checkall">
                </td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=3">3</a></td>
                <td>Conta Serviço A <span class="label active">Active</span></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientsservices.php?userid=1&amp;id=3"><kbd>semdomain@config...</kbd></a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/clientssummary.php?userid=1">Teste Teste</a></td>
                <td>R$0.00 BRL</td>
                <td>Gratuito</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Código da tabela dinâmica: https://jsfiddle.net/FloridaStream/391vumzg/1/

Comment: Gostaria de entender o motivo do -1, para que eu possa melhorar a questão, uma explicação seria bem-vinda, grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que vc pode fazer eh algo parecido com isso.Eh para funcionar nesse caso tambem(semdomain@config...)?

Nesse caso esse codigo so pega os emails validos.

```
$(function(){
    $("td a").each(function(){
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      var content = $(this).html();
      //console.log(content);
      if(re.test(String(content).toLowerCase())){
        $(this).html("<kbd>"+content+"</kbd>"); 
      }
  })

 });
```

Comment: Sim, é pra funcionar com `@config...`, pois nesse caso ainda não tem domínio configurado.

Comment: Adicionei `|(config...)` a expressão regular, isso atende perfeitamente a questão proposta aqui, estou marcando como respondida. Caso outros também desejem responder, fiquem a vontade para demonstrar outros meios. :)

Comment: Desculpa, eu entrei em uma reuniao aqui e nao tinha conseguido mudar o codigo para vc. Que bom que deu tudo certo!